# How to correctly write the path(useNavigate)?

Tags: reactjs

please help. I have such a route, how to correctly specify the path in the navigate before it

```
  if (data) { navigate({`MainPage/repos/users:${inputValue}/page/`}); } 



  <Route
      path={`MainPage/repos/users:${inputValue}/page/`}
      element={(
        <MainPage
          userProfile={userProfile}
          loading={loading}
          reposRef={reposRef}
          setinputValue={setinputValue}
          githubPageref={githubPageref}
          findUser={findUser}
          getMoreRepos={getMoreRepos}
          pageSize={pageSize}
        />
      )}
    />
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you don't need to pass braces in `navigate`, try this:

```
if (data) { navigate(`MainPage/repos/users:${inputValue}/page/`); }
```